# passing complex object to rest wcf

Tags: wcf, rest, c#-4.0, wcf-binding, wcf-security

Passing custom object to REST WCF operation is giving me "bad request error". I have tried here with both uri path and query string type methods.Any help is greatly appreciated.

**service side code**

```
[ServiceContract]    
public interface IRestService
{       

   [OperationContract]        
   [WebInvoke(UriTemplate  = "getbook?tc={tc}",Method="POST",BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
   string GetBook(myclass mc);
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(myclass))]
public class myclass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }        
}

public string GetBookById(myclass mc)
{            
    return mc.name;
}
```

**client side code:**

```
public static void GetString()
{
    myclass mc = new myclass();            
    mc.name = "demo";           

    string jsn = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(mc);

    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format(@"http://localhost:55218/RestService.svc/getbook?mc={0}",jsn));

    string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("bda11d91-7ere-4da1-2e5d-24adfe39d174"));
    req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials);
    req.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 2147483647;
    req.Method = "POST";           
    req.ContentType = "application/json";   
    // exception is thrown here         
    using (WebResponse svcResponse = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(svcResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
          JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
          string jsonTxt = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

**service config**

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="01:01:00"
    openTimeout="01:01:00" receiveTimeout="01:10:00" sendTimeout="01:01:00"
    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"  hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
    maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed"
    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
      maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    <security mode="None">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
        realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
    </security>
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>

<webHttpBinding>
  <binding name="" closeTimeout="01:01:00" openTimeout="01:01:00" 
    receiveTimeout="01:10:00" sendTimeout="01:01:00" allowCookies="false"
    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
    maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
    transferMode="Streamed" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
      maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    <security mode="None" />
   </binding>
 </webHttpBinding>
 </bindings>

<services>
  <service name="WcfRestSample.RestService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="WcfRestSample.IRestService" />        
    <!--<host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/restservice" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>-->
  </service>
</services>
<!-- behaviors settings -->
<behaviors>     

  <!-- end point behavior-->
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="restfulBehavior">          
      <webHttp/>               
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="WcfRestSample.APIKeyAuthorization, WcfRestSample" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>      
 </behaviors>
 <standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint
      automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"
      helpEnabled="true" />
 </webHttpEndpoint>
 </standardEndpoints>
 <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
 </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: You are using the bodystyle attribute as wrapped but am assuming that the request is not wrapped accordingly. Can you change the bodystyle attribute value to Bare and try. Also please inspect the Raw request using Fiddler and post the request here to help you out

Comment: Please post your service configuration file as well.

Comment: I have updated my question which includes service config also. Here, in this code I am trying to call another service(i.e., service.svc) for which I have set basichttpbinding configuration. Call to this second service also throwing bad request error. I don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Operation 'getbook' in contract 'IRestService' has a query variable named 'tc' of type 'WcfRestSample.newclass', but type 'WcfRestSample.newclass' is not convertible by 'QueryStringConverter'. Variables for UriTemplate query values must have types that can be converted by 'QueryStringConverter'. This is raw data captured from fiddler.

Comment: The moment I add class type parameter or other parameter along with stream my service not allowing me to view in browser. It is showing error that you can't have more than one parameter when using stream and if I use class parameter it is showing me query string parameter must be string. Due to this am finding difficulty to debug into the service because my primary service is making call to another secondary service. How to overcome this or suppress this issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems to be fine, except that you have to wrap the data in a wrapper, and that is when you get the json data as `{"mc":{"name":"Java"}}` else you will get only `{"name":"Java"}` which is not a wrapped request. All these is required because you have set the **WebMessageBodyStyle** as **Wrapped**.

Below is the code.

```
  [OperationContract]
            [WebInvoke( Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
            string GetBook(myclass mc);

     [DataContract]    
        public class myclass
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string name { get; set; }
        }

public string GetBook(myclass mc)
            {
                return mc.name;
            }
```

Client:

```
  public class wrapper
    {
        public myclass mc;
    }
    public class myclass
    {
        public String name;
    }

    myclass mc = new myclass();
                mc.name = "Java";
                wrapper senddata = new wrapper();
                senddata.mc = mc;
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] data = encoder.GetBytes(js.Serialize(senddata));
                HttpWebRequest req2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(String.Format(@"http://localhost:1991/Service1.svc/GetBook?"));
                req2.Method = "POST";
                req2.ContentType = @"application/json; charset=utf-8";
                req2.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 2147483647;
                req2.ContentLength = data.Length;
                req2.GetRequestStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req2.GetResponse();
                string jsonResponse = string.Empty;
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    jsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    Response.Write(jsonResponse);
                }
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: I am also looking same.. but if you use BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped then you will have problem in using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.PopulateObject since your json response will have parent property with something like {"GetxxResult": {} }