# RESTful service - handle custom objects in the request

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, wcf, rest

My apologies if this is such a basic question - Im new to RESTful services, namely WCF rest based services.

I am creating a WCF service for an iPad app to consume.  The data requests and responses will be JSON - I have created some dummy hello worlds that use a URI Template to pass data, and it works just fine.

Where Im confused now is, if my method signature requires a complex type, such as a custom object, how is that data requested via my service?  Do I respond to a "PUT" or "POST" verb?  Is it something entirely different?

Comment: Ack, why are you building a WCF service? You should really look at [WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api). There's lot of examples/tutorials out there of how to accept complex types (eg: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api), these days usually everything is encoded as JSON but WebAPI supports other formats as well (including XML).

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20651645/passing-complex-object-to-rest-wcf

Comment: Thanks @SelvaTS looks to me like it's just a POST of JSON to my service then, appreciate the confirmation.

Comment: @gregmac thanks for the advice as well, trying to get the service switched over to WebAPI but at this time, client has requested WCF...

Comment: [From Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172(v=vs.110).aspx): "Use ASP.NET Web API if you are creating and designing new REST-style services. Although WCF provides some support for writing REST-style services, the support for REST in ASP.NET Web API is more complete and all future REST feature improvements will be made in ASP.NET Web API. " ... Just in case you need ammunition.