# How pass parameter to Rest WCF Service from MVC5 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, rest, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a WCF Rest Service(using Json) that gets the username and password and returns Customer information. This is the Method interface.

```
   //Get Customer by Name
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke
       (UriTemplate = "/GetCustomerByName",
        Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
        )]
    List<Model.Customer> GetCustomerByName(Model.CustomerName CustomerData);
```

I need to call this method in MVC5 and pass parameter to it. Not sure how to pass parameter.

This is how I call the service:

```
readonly string customerServiceUri = "http://localhost:63674/CSA.svc/";
 public ActionResult SearchByName(InputData model)
    {
        List<CustomerModel> customerModel = new List<CustomerModel>();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (model != null)
            {
                using (WebClient webclient = new WebClient())
                {
                    string jsonStr = webclient.DownloadString(string.Format("{0}GetCustomerByName?CustomerData={1}", customerServiceUri, model));

                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jsonStr))
                    {
                        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.CustomerModel.Result>(jsonStr);

                        if (result != null)
                        {
                            customerModel = result.GetCustomersByNameResult;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return View(customerModel);
    }
```

I am getting error right on this line:

```
 string jsonStr = webclient.DownloadString(string.Format("{0}GetCustomerByName?CustomerData={1}", customerServiceUri, model));
```

and this is the error:

> The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

and this is **InputData** class:

```
 public class InputData
  {

      public string First_Name { get; set; }
      public string Last_Name { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: Why you use `Method = "POST"` and not `Method = "GET"`?

Comment: @adricadar not sure I thought as I am posting username and password to it. I changes it to Get and I am getting this error: "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."

Comment: I asked why not `GET` because from your method name `GetCustomerByName` i inherited that you want to make a `GET` request.

Comment: Also you get `(405) Method Not Allowed` because you expecting a `POST` and making a `GET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the line of code is calling the service, wrong. Because you pass the values in url, the line of code is making an `GET` request, **not** a `POST`. If you are willing to make a `POST` request please [follow this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20651645/passing-complex-object-to-rest-wcf).

**What is wrong with the code?**

```
string jsonStr = webclient.DownloadString(string.Format("{0}GetCustomerByName?CustomerData={1}", customerServiceUri, model));
```

1) This error is thrown `(405) Method Not Allowed because you expecting` because a `POST` request is expected and is made a `GET` request.

2) This will output something like this: `http://localhost:63674/CSA.svc/GetCustomerByName?CustomerData=[SolutionName].[ProjectName].InputData`

This is happening because C# don't know how to convert `InputData` to string in the way you want, for this you have to *override* the method `ToString()`.

**Possible solution**

Try to make a `GET` request, you have to call the service in this way (with few modifications)

```
string jsonStr = webclient.DownloadString(string.Format("{0}GetCustomerByName?firstName={1}&lastName={2}", customerServiceUri, model.First_Name, model.Last_Name));
```

You have to modify the service to match the example i made for the `GET` request.

```
//Get Customer by Name
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetCustomerByName?firstName={firstName}&lastName={lastName}")]
List<Model.Customer> GetCustomerByName(string firstName, string lastName);
```

Comment: again same error, when I use Post I am getting this error.The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed. and when I use Get I am getting this error:"The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."

Comment: @nikoom if you want to make a `GET`, you have to modify the service method, i will edit my answer how. If you are willing to make a `POST` request follow this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20651645/passing-complex-object-to-rest-wcf

Comment: can't have this in service. then service gave me this error. Operation 'GetCustomerByName' in contract 'ICSA' uses GET, but also has body parameter 'firstName'. GET operations cannot have a body. Either make the parameter 'firstName' a UriTemplate parameter, or switch from WebGetAttribute to WebInvokeAttribute.